# org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5 hash for file

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-15

when i import project by gradle
idea throw build fail error,this is [error screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FLyJ.png)
but when i user command `gradle clean bootrun`,it works ok,this is [works screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nt01.png)
this is [my env setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJcWb.png).
could you give me some help, thanks , i am really confused

Comment: by the way, my intellij-idea version is 2018.1

Comment: Which was the solution

Comment: i solved  it by moveing to an new  mac book